# NGINX location blocks not loading content

Tags: nginx

I have a new NGINX installation that is running and, to an extent, working (I can see default nginx landing page on host.com/).
In my config I have 3 location blocks. with the following patterns:

```
/
/register
/keycloak
```

As mentioned, the first one works. Loads landing page fine.
the second two fail to load the content their proxy_pass identifies.

```
location /register {
  proxy_pass http://register;
}

location /keycloak {
   proxy_pass http://keycloak;
}
```

The curious thing is that when I update the default (/) block from:

```
location / {
  root   html;
  index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

to:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://register;
}
```

or

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://keycloak
}
```

It serves correct content as I would like /register /keycloak to do.

My nginx installation is running on a machine on its own and the register and keycloak services are running on another server in the same lan. I can ping the server from nginx server and can curl both services from nginx server.

Answer (score 1):

i needed a trailing / at the end of the proxy_pass url.

from this:

```
location /keycloak {
   proxy_pass http://keycloak;
}
```

to this:

```
location /keycloak {
   proxy_pass http://keycloak/;
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.